# Multi-tenant in Broadleaf

Tags: e-commerce, multi-tenant, broadleaf-commerce

I am new to Broadleaf. And i am trying to do multitenant in it.

I can't find any documentation in Broadleaf official site. I found one project in github about multitenancy in broadleaf.That's the link 
https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite-MultiTenant-SingleSchema

As i build that project in maven through "mvn install", its getting build failure, below error comes as i build that project.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ecommerce ......................................... SUCCESS [0.619s]
[INFO] core .............................................. SUCCESS [1:35.628s]
[INFO] admin ............................................. FAILURE [27.273s]
[INFO] site .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:03.894s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 03 10:08:01 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/60M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:admin:war:1.0: Could not find artifact com.broadleafcommerce:broadleaf-multitenant-singleschema:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in snapshots (http://192.168.1.10:8080/artifactory/libs-snapshot) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :admin
```

Maybe it states that it can't find the broadleaf-multitenant-singleschema jar that define in pom.xml.

```
  <dependency>
                <groupId>com.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
                <artifactId>broadleaf-multitenant-singleschema</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
```

I tried to find that jar manually , but I can't found that jar.
I can't figure out what's the problem is. 
Is it possible to do multitenant in broadleaf ?
Is that demo is about multitenant in broadleaf ?

Thanks in advance.
Ankit

Comment: Actually the demo that i refer is for Enterprise-addition of broadleaf. So it can't support into the community version, and i am using community version. So i am getting this error while building the project.

Answer (score 0):

glad to hear that you are trying out Broadleaf!

As you mentioned in your comment, the Broadleaf Multitenant Singleschema module is a commercial module, not a community module. Another point: Broadleaf itself (as in the core Broadleaf framework) is all open source. There is no separate commercial version of the core Broadleaf code base. However, some of the modules that we offer are commercial. Multitenant is one of them, along with things like change sets and other 3rd-party integrations (like Braintree or Sagepay).

If you would like some additional information about the multitenant module, feel free to shoot us an email at info AT broadleafcommerce.com.

Source: being a Broadleaf employee :)

Comment: Hi phillipuniverse,
I am trying to do the tutorials of the broadleaf from the http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/ link.

What i found that the demo looks easy but they didn't specify the package where to define classes. For example , http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/dev/Adding-Customer-Attribute-Tutorial.html , in this link where to create classes, in which package structure ?

Comment: Answered your forum post at http://forum.broadleafcommerce.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=1889&p=5216#p5216